# Conditionally change value of ng-model for input

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have following HTML code:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="search.isOrdered"/>
```

If user types `ordered` word to input then I want `ng-model = true`, if user types `unordered` word to input, then I want `ng-model = false`. In other cases I want to `ng-model = undefined` or `ng-model = null`. Suppose I can't use radio-button or checkbox.

How to achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: I think you'll have to use `ng-change` and set `search.isOrdered` based on a different `ng-model` you use for this textbox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your HTML as follows:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="search.isOrderedInput"/>
```

In your controller:

```
    $scope.isOrdered = function() {
        var isOrdered;

        switch ($scope.isOrderedInput) {
        case 'ordered':
            isOrdered = true;
            break;
        case 'unordered':
            isOrdered = false;
            break;
        default:
            isOrdered = undefined;
            break;

        }

        return isOrdered;
    };
```

This should be more maintainable than adding logic to the view via ng-change, no?

Answer (score 3):

Use `ng-change` instead:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="search.order" ng-change="search.isOrdered = search.order == 'ordered'"/>
```

See [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/A47E4/1/)